# Общие сессии php и javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Столкнулся с необходимостью общих сессий в джаваскрипте и пхп. 
Тоесть, что-бы сессию, которую объявили в ПХП можно было пользоваться через джаваскрипт. Гуглил, гугл выдавал старые и не очень результаты, где писалось - это невозможно сделать изящно. Там-же предлагался метод, который, в моём случае, оказался рабочим.

```
var varname="<?php echo $_SESSION['key']; ?>";
```

Хотел спросить, может уже есть более изящные методы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать возможность подгрузки данных сессии через ajax.

Сделайте скрипт `getSessionData.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($_SESSION);
```

Из javascript делаете ajax-запрос и получаете все данные сессии скопом.
(реализацию функции ajax() оставляю за Вами)

```
ajax(function(data){
  sessionData = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Этот метод легко расширить
(добавить возможность js изменять серверные данные и тп)

Answer (score 0):

Сессия - это хранилище данных в одном месте и передача связующего идентификатора в другое место. Тогда достаточно просто его послать и как будто переслал все данные (они берутся из хранилища). Выходит у второй стороны этих данных просто нет.

Если нужен обоюдный доступ к данным - куки в руки! Можно, конечно, придумать много способов - от организации сессии в локальном хранилище, до прямого вшивания значений сессии в переменные JS, как в примере.
Но вопрос - надо ли это?

Answer (score -1):

Самый хороший вариант - записать сессию в переменную JS, как у тебя и сделано.

Куки ограниченны по размеру и будут гоняться туда-сюда между сервером и клиентом (это ведь просто HTTP заголовки), AJAX - это лишний запрос со всеми вытекающими последствиями + возможность получить неактуальные данные (одну и ту же сессию можно поменять почти одновременно из двух параллельных вкладок хрома, например).

Localstorage я бы не стал использовать - потому что данные в нем сохраняются между запросами и можно на клиенте нарваться на некорректные и невалидные (читай - просроченные данные сессии). Например, если по какой-то причине php скрипт не дойдет до момента генерации нужно куска кода.

```
<script>
  window.sessionData = '<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION); ?>'
</script>
```

Так ты гарантированно получаешь на клиенте сессию, которая была актуальна на момент обработки сервером запроса.